# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - June 2019

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 21st edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for June 2019

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              440
2   bmike                     270
3   nohillside                240
4   fsb                       160
5   ankiiiiiii                120
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 1,150.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,650 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2019-06-01).<sup>1</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              267
2   bmike                      94
3   nohillside                 63
4   IconDaemon                 52
5   ankiiiiiii                 49
```

A big thank you to all 17 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,266
2   bmike                     252
3   ankiiiiiii                210
4   Nimesh Neema              207
5   Monomeeth                 136
```

A big thank you to all 50 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>2</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 58
2   Nimesh Neema               57
3   bmike                      28
4   fsb                        22
5   Glorfindel                 15
```

A big thank you to all 19 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              362
2   Greenonline               103
3   fsb                        91
4   ankiiiiiii                 83
5   Monomeeth                  47
```

A big thank you to all 28 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               70
2   fsb                        32
3   Tetsujin                   23
4   Greenonline                20
5   ankiiiiiii                 17
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               37
2   nohillside                 13
3   fsb                        12
4   bmike                      11
5   Glorfindel                 10
```

A big thank you to all 14 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 15
2   Nimesh Neema                9
3   fsb                         6
4   bmike, Tetsujin             5
5   Glorfindel                  3
```

A big thank you to all 9 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 84
2   Nimesh Neema               71
3   bmike                      33
4   Glorfindel                 29
5   fsb                        26
```

A big thank you to all 34 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [What are the practical differences between Bash and Zsh?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-bash-and-zsh)

   - Posted by: dr.nixon
   - Votes: **42**
2. [What can I, as a user, do about offensive reviews in App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361471/what-can-i-as-a-user-do-about-offensive-reviews-in-app-store)

   - Posted by: Neith
   - Votes: **40**
3. [How do I type a hyphen in iOS 12?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362020/how-do-i-type-a-hyphen-in-ios-12)

   - Posted by: Harper
   - Votes: **18**
4. [How Do I Know When I am in Private Mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363203/how-do-i-know-when-i-am-in-private-mode)

   - Posted by: EdgeCase
   - Votes: **15**
5. [Dual boot macOS Catalina 10.15 beta and macOS Mojave 10.14](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361534/dual-boot-macos-catalina-10-15-beta-and-macos-mojave-10-14)

   - Posted by: rmaddy
   - Votes: **13**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [What can I, as a user, do about offensive reviews in App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361488/168832)

   - Posted by: TJ Luoma
   - Votes: **58**
2. [What are the practical differences between Bash and Zsh?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361957/168832)

   - Posted by: Gilles
   - Votes: **48**
3. [What is the “ls” directory in my home directory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362493/168832)

   - Posted by: jksoegaard
   - Votes: **37**
4. [How do I type a hyphen in iOS 12?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362025/168832)

   - Posted by: muru
   - Votes: **19**
5. [How Do I Know When I am in Private Mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363212/168832)

   - Posted by: Lizzan
   - Votes: **18**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [What can I, as a user, do about offensive reviews in App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361471/what-can-i-as-a-user-do-about-offensive-reviews-in-app-store)

   - Posted by: Neith
   - Votes: **8,275**
2. [How can I recover from a "AMD-Action:downloadProduct:SP" during installation of macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361464/how-can-i-recover-from-a-amd-actiondownloadproductsp-during-installation-of)

   - Posted by: Joseph Shaw
   - Views: **6,411**
3. [Dual boot macOS Catalina 10.15 beta and macOS Mojave 10.14](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361534/dual-boot-macos-catalina-10-15-beta-and-macos-mojave-10-14)

   - Posted by: rmaddy
   - Views: **5,628**
4. [What is the "ls" directory in my home directory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362492/what-is-the-ls-directory-in-my-home-directory)

   - Posted by: Panda
   - Votes: **4,124**
5. [What are the practical differences between Bash and Zsh?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-bash-and-zsh)

   - Posted by: dr.nixon
   - Votes: **3,411**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [dr.nixon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/11587/dr-nixon)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [TJ Luoma](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9226/tj-luoma)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [Neith](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/201427/neith)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In June our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **203 flags** with an average handling time of **28 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 211 comments
- deleted 83 posts
- closed 191 posts
- edited 241 posts
- created 42 posts
- created 288 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

---

<sup>**1.** Due to the possibility of profile changes over time, this link may not reflect the screenshot above.</sup>

<sup>**2.** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>